# Observing changes to an ItemController in Array Controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I've been learning ember by recreating the TodoMVC in EmberCli. Ive recreated all the functionality, but I ran into an issue and I was hoping someone could shed some light on the situation.

It seems that my Todos ArrayController will observe and fire functions when properties in my model change but not when values in my Todo ObjectController change.

I moved isEditing into the Model so that when I call `editTodo` `canToggle` fires. But I would prefer to store that value in my controller and not the model.

I set up a test with with a propTest boolean. on a button click I fire `propToggle`but `todoPropToggle` doesn't respond to the change. The only time that it does ever fire is on initialization.

Any insight would be super helpful.

TODOS CONTROLLER

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
actions: {
  createTodo: function() {
    var title = this.get('newTitle');
    if (!title.trim()) {
      return;
    }
    var todo = this.store.createRecord('todo', {
      title: title,
      isCompleted: false,
      isEditing:false
    });

    this.set('newTitle', '');
    todo.save();
    }
  },

  canToggle: function() {
    var isEditing = this.isAny('isEditing');
    return this.get('length') && !isEditing;
  }.property('length','@each.isEditing'),

  todoPropToggle: function() {
    var hasPropTest = this.isAny('propTest');
    return hasPropTest;
  }.property('@each.propTest')
});
```

TODO CONTROLLER

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  actions: {
    editTodo: function() {
      var todo = this.get('model');
      todo.set('isEditing', true);
    },

    removeTodo: function() {
      var todo = this.get('model');
      todo.deleteRecord();
      todo.save();
    },

    acceptChanges: function() {
      var todo = this.get('model');
      todo.set('isEditing', false);
      if (Ember.isEmpty(this.get('model.title'))) {
        this.send('removeTodo');
      }
      else {
        this.get('model').save();
      }
    },

    propToggle:function(){
      this.set('propTest',!this.get('propTest'));
    }
  },

  propTest:true,

  isCompleted: function(key, value) {
    var model = this.get('model');
    if (value === undefined) {
      return model.get('isCompleted');
    }
    else {
      model.set('isCompleted', value);
      model.save();
      return value;
    }
  }.property('model.isCompleted')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about an alternative approach? We could toggle 'canToggle' in arrayController directly from the object controller by either using parentController or specifying needs. Avoids having to observer all the itemControllers which should be more efficient too.

TODOS CONTROLLER:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default
Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    /**
    * references the todo model that is currently being edited
    */
    editingTodo: null,
    canToggle: Ember.computed.notEmpty('editingTodo'),

    actions: {
        createTodo: function () {
            var title = this.get('newTitle');
            if (!title.trim()) {
                return;
            }
            var todo = this.store.createRecord('todo', {
                title: title,
                isCompleted: false,
                isEditing: false
            });

            this.set('newTitle', '');
            todo.save();
        }
    }
});
```

TODO CONTROLLER

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default
Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    needs:['todos']
    todos : Ember.computed.alias('controllers.todos'),

    actions: {
        editTodo: function () {
            this.set('todos.editingTodo', this.get('model'));
        },

        removeTodo: function () {
            var todo = this.get('model');
            if (this.get('todos.editingTodo') === todo) {
                this.set('todos.editingTodo', null);
            }
            todo.deleteRecord();
            todo.save();
        },

        acceptChanges: function () {
            this.set('todos.editingTodo', null);
            if (Ember.isEmpty(this.get('model.title'))) {
                this.send('removeTodo');
            }
            else {
                this.get('model').save();
            }
        }
    },

    isCompleted: function (key, value) {
        var model = this.get('model');
        if (value === undefined) {
            return model.get('isCompleted');
        }
        else {
            model.set('isCompleted', value);
            model.save();
            return value;
        }
    }.property('model.isCompleted')
});
```

I have not tested it, but I hope you get the jist of the solution I am proposing.

Comment: That does seem to work, but that is really an end around for what I would like to be doing. Is this really the best practice for this type of functionality? Based on the code in the TodoMVC example I was expecting cleaner way.

Comment: I guess another solution which might be better is the route based solution. So in your todo route, use the activate and deactivate hooks to set the canToggle property in the todos controller.

Comment: Does that mean that there is no way to observe a object controllers property from an array controller?

Comment: In my experience observing array properties seem to cause quite a performance impact so i tend to stay away from it if possible. Also i am not sure if you can access item controllers from parent, but if you 'really' need to observe item controllers then you can push your item controllers to the array controller when you initialize your todo controller - which i think is even worse solution. Personally i think you should be able to do what you want to just by using setupController in your todo route or the other hooks i mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

`propTest` in this scenario here looks like it's a computed property, and not an observable.  (edit: not that computed properties don't have underlying observables powering them, but they're different in usage enough that I like to keep them separate) It'll fire when the underlying propTest fires, but if there's no change, ember will no-op that out in the run loop.  If you'd rather this be a raw observable, use the `observes()` syntax.  `@each` will work here, but I like being explicit and have an observable update what it needs to rather than using the computed property, unless I need direct access to that property to bind with in a template.

The "only firing on execution" stems from the initial bindings from the computed property getting created.  If it never fires after that, the underlying bindings you're using for the computed property `@each.propTest` must be incorrect, otherwise that would indeed fire.

I think you may also be confused to the purpose of an ObjectController.  An `Ember.Object` can do all of the observable business that a controller can, short of having a 'model' or 'content' property backing it.  It looks like you may want to go with a straight up object rather than a controller here for the todo, since ember doesn't really have a 'model' type.   I'd then put the objects themselves as part of the content of the ArrayController, at which point @each would be able to iterate on them as you'd expect.

The ObjectController sits at the same level of usage as an ArrayController.  You can certainly nest them as you've done here, but my spidey-sense is tingling that it's the wrong thing to do given the application.  You probably don't need to have a backing controller for each todo object, you just need the todo object itself.