# Observe when any Ember.ObjectController in Ember.ArrayController changes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to set up mass-action checkboxes (for something like Delete Selected Items) in an Ember App. The idea is to make a mass-action dropdown show or hide if any one of the checkboxes are selected. I haven't put in the dropdown yet since I can't figure out how to observe all elements in the array. How can I:

1. Set up the Array controller so it observes all client objects
2. Get the number of checked items when it changes
3. ALSO: Am I on track with the conventions of how I'm approaching the client itemController?

**app/templates/clients.hbs**

```
<section id="clients">
    <h4>my clients</h4>
    <ul>
    {{#each itemController="clients/client"}}
        <li>
            {{input type="checkbox" name="markedForDeletion" checked=markedForDeletion}}
            {{#link-to 'clients.show' this}}
                {{clientName}}
            {{/link-to}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}

    </ul>
</section>
{{#link-to 'clients.new'}}Add client{{/link-to}}
{{outlet}}
```

**router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

export default Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('clients', function() {
    this.route('show', {path: '/:client_id'});
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

**app/routes/clients.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('client');
    }
});
```

**app/models/client.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  clientName: DS.attr('string'),
  clientEmail: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**app/controllers/clients.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    checkBoxesChanged: function() {
    // This fires only once, when the /clients/ route is activated
    console.log('markedForDeletion in array changed');
  }.observes('@each.clients')
});
```

**app/controllers/clients/client.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    markedForDeletion: true,
    markedForDeletionChanged: function(){
        // This fires correctly
        console.log('markedForDeletion object changed');
    }.observes('markedForDeletion')
});
```

Edit: Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774035/observing-changes-to-an-itemcontroller-in-array-controller), but I'm afraid the answers didn't help me all that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions to this. Since your solution only requires the need for an extra property of being checked, I think that an ObjectProxy will meet your needs. If, however, you needed more functionality, then a component would be a better fit.

**Note:** Before we dive into the solution, though, it's important to note that ArrayController, ObjectController, and ItemController are all being deprecated.

Since we won't be using itemController, you can remove **app/controllers/clients/client.js**

**app/templates/clients.hbs**

```
<section id="clients">
    <h4>my clients</h4>
    <ul>
    {{#each clientsWithMarker as |client|}}
        <li>
            {{input type="checkbox" name="markedForDeletion" checked=client.markedForDeletion}}
            {{#link-to 'clients.show' client}}
                {{client.clientName}}
            {{/link-to}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}

    </ul>
</section>
{{#link-to 'clients.new'}}Add client{{/link-to}}
{{outlet}}
```

**app/controllers/clients.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    clientsWithMarker: Ember.computed.map('model', function(client) {
        return Ember.ObjectProxy.create({
            content: client,
            checked: false
        });
    }),

    // This computed property returns an array of ObjectProxies that
    // are checked. It is recalculated automatically
    checkedClients: Ember.computed.filterBy('clientsWithMarker', 'checked', true),

    checkBoxesChanged: function() {
    // This fires only once, when the /clients/ route is activated
    console.log('markedForDeletion in array changed');
  }.observes('clientsWithMarker.@each.checked')
});
```

This *should* work, but I haven't actually tested this specific code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example of Multi-Select Checkbox functionality implementation in ember.

http://alexdiliberto.com/posts/ember-toggle-all-checkbox/

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/coliwiwa/5/edit?html,css,js,output

Basically when looping through each item in array, the itemController sends reference of itself to parentController and parentController maintains these references in an array. Here `isChecked` property is defined inside each itemController instead of attaching to array members.
We are using this approach in our production code.

Alternative approach could be to use `ObjectProxy` and attach `isChecked` property on each array item of new array, and observe it.

eg. If `colors` is array then

```
var newColors = colors.map(function(color){
 return Ember.ObjectProxy.create({
   isChecked: false, 
   content: color
   } 
)};
```

This way we have create newColors array with `isChecked` property which we can loop over and we haven't touched the individual items.